# VHDL: The following files are missing: .stx, .ncd, .xrpt

Tags: file, save, warnings, vhdl, synthesis

Before I even start with synthesis(as soon as I press "Save"), I get this warnings:

```
WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Counter.stx is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Counter_map.ncd is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Counter_xst.xrpt is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Test.stx is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Counter.stx is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Counter_map.ncd is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Counter_xst.xrpt is missing.

WARNING:ProjectMgmt - File C:/Users/bojanm/Desktop/Enkoder-Digital Output/Test/Test.stx is missing.
```

Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like you have part of a Xilinx project there. Those are files *generated* by the tools but apparently the project manager expects them to be there already. Probably "Project/Cleanup Project Files" will get you to a state where you can synthesise and regenerate them.

Comment: @БојанДругарМатовски Have you found a solution to overcome this warning

Comment: Try to use directory names without spaces in it. ISE used to have problems with those, I'm not sure if it still does in its current version, tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple go to: **Project** tab then go to **Cleanup Project Files** and click **ON**. Now, run your file.